# Defect in H2 TRUNC function

Tags: sql, h2

Starting from version 1.3.172, there is a `TRUNC` function which is supposed to mimic the Oracle's `TRUNC(TIMESTAMP)`.  There is a slight problem with the implementation.  Query:

```
select TRUNC(TIMESTAMP '2000-02-04 11:13:14') from dual;
```

returns "2000-02-04 00:00:00" as expected, but:

```
select TRUNC(TIMESTAMP '2000-02-04 15:13:14') from dual;
```

returns "2000-02-04 12:00:00", which is wrong.

The reason for this is the incorrect implementation (starting from line 1031 of Function.java), we see:

```
case TRUNCATE: {
    if (v0.getType() == Value.TIMESTAMP) {
        java.sql.Timestamp d = v0.getTimestamp();
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(d);
        c.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
```

The `c.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0)` should be replaced by `c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)` --- otherwise it truncates the 12-hour clock (which mimics the oracle version only for times before noon).

Is there any hope of including this kind of fix in near future?

I'd push the fix myself, but I 'stackoverflow h2 tag' was the only 'support' link I could find, so that's where I'm reporting the problem.

In the meantime (while I wait for the fix to become accessible), is it possible to replace (say, by dropping the existing alias and replacing it with a different implementation)?

Answer (score 1):

In the [H2 web site](http://h2database.com/html/main.html), there are 3 links under "Support": [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/h2), [Google Group English](http://groups.google.com/group/h2-database) and [Japanese](http://groups.google.co.jp/group/h2-database-jp). For bug reports, it makes sense to use the Google Group.

The feature to truncate timestamps is relatively new. The bug you found was already found by somebody else and is fixed in the trunk. If you want, you can try it out by downloading and building H2 yourself.

Comment: Thanks, will try the google group.  Sorry... google group didn't make sense for bug report as all 3 were under 'support' and stackoverflow being first.  My other questions still stand: is it possible to replace existing trunc?  I tried the 'trunk' version... it doesn't have the 12h problem, but there are still several others: trunc(1.3) throws NullPointerException (so does trunc(null)) and trunc(date) complains about conversion problem.

Comment: You are right, trunc(1.3) throws NullPointerException, I will fix that. Thanks for reporting the issue! However trunc(null) didn't throw a exception in my test. Why do you want to use `trunc(date)`?

Comment: Thanks. I know it's probably not the use you envisioned H2 for, but I'm using it for 'unit testing' (let's not dwell on the question if it's really 'unit' or not, shall we?).  Anyway, my primary db is oracle, where trunc(date) is 'normal' way of stripping time from date.  I want to use H2 without actually changing the queries.  Not a perfect test, but fast.

Comment: @ishi A lot of people use H2 for testing, that's OK. The problem is that some people use MySQL for production, some use Oracle, some use PostgreSQL, and so on. That means they expect H2 to be compatible with all those databases, which is obviously very hard to achieve. All those databases are not compatible with one another, but people expect that H2 is compatible with all of them...

Comment: I never expected it to be fully compatible.  You asked why I use trunc(date) and this was my answer --- because I use it in oracle.  As for compatibility, there is some parameter in connection string which sets it to be more oracle flavour, I believe.  I'm not an expert on database cross-compatibility, but I believe that trunc(date), if at all defined in a given database, would always return the date w/o time.

Comment: One other thing...  How about adding a functionality to override pre-defined functions?  This way I could write my own implementation of trunc and it could behave in any way I want...  You could even get people to contribute such db-specific function implementations

Comment: I see your point, but overriding system functions is problematic, specially those that need special parsing support (trunc is not one of those I believe). But generally, patches are welcome!